# Google Chrome Extension using page sources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, qlikview

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension for a QlikView dashboard.

```
  Qva.BodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(init())
    function init() {

      alert("init!");
  }
```

I got **Qva is not defined** error which I don't have running the same code from the Developer Tools console. I guess I have to include the QlikView js library somehow. (/QvAjaxZfc/htc/QvAjax.js)
Do you have any idea how to achieve that? I am pretty new in Js & Google extensions. And I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: To access it you need to run a [script in page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Thanks, it is working flawlessly with the injection.